# Error Storing Docker Credentials with docker-credential-secretservice: 'executable file not found in $PATH'

Tags: docker, authentication, debian, docker-desktop

I have a Debian laptop (Linux debian 6.1.0-11-amd64) where I've installed both Docker Engine and Docker Desktop. I successfully logged in to Docker Hub using Mozilla Firefox (Version 102.14.0esr). After installation, I generated a GPG public key using the 'gpg --generate-key' command, which displayed success. In Docker Desktop, I'm also logged in to my account. However, when I try to run 'docker login' in the command line, I encounter the error 'Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-secretservice": executable file not found in $PATH'. How can I resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

I installed Docker Engine and Docker Desktop on my Debian laptop (Linux debian 6.1.0-11-amd64) and successfully logged in to Docker Hub using Mozilla Firefox (Version 102.14.0esr). After the installation, I generated a GPG public key using the 'gpg --generate-key' command, which displayed success. In Docker Desktop, I'm also logged in to my account. When I attempted to run 'docker login' in the command line, I expected the login process to proceed smoothly. However, I encountered the error message 'Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exec: "docker-credential-secretservice": executable file not found in $PATH'. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.